# Proof for $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$ from ProofWiki

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am looking through some proof on ProofWiki and found this for the identity $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$. I follow the proof but having trouble understanding the "hence the result". Why does it follow from the previous line that $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cauchy-Binet formula gives the determinant of any square $AB$. The proof's final paragraph addresses the case where $A,,B$ are individually square. Since $m=n$, there is only one way to choose $m$ strictly increasing indices from $1$ to $n$, viz. $j_l=l$. So the formula's right-hand side is a single term, which is $\det A\det B$.

Comment: To add: the summation has only one term and $A_{j_1j_2\cdots j_n}=A$, same for $B$.